# How to set search scope in radare2

Tags: radare2

Iam wondering how to change search scope in radare2. I`ve made some research and set variables `search.from` and `search.to`, according to Radare2 Book, but it doesn't work at all! 
[image: Screenshot from R2, setting search scope.]

Could you help me with this one?

r2 -v `radare2 3.6.0-git 22077 @ linux-x86-64 git.3.5.1-256-ga49bb7cf6`

Comment: I've checked this in ver 3.6 on Windows and 3.7 on Linux and don't observe such behavior but your prompt `:>` suggest that you are in some different mode.

Comment: It's visual mode. 
I've checked on command-line prompt, and behaviour its even more weird. ```0x00401152]> e search.from=0x4000000```
```[0x00401152]> e search.to = 0x41000000```
```[0x00401152]> / justtest```
```[0x00401152]> ```

It didnt show anything after search command.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found the solution.

In case anybody has same issue. You have to set search.in value to "range" in order to "tell" r2 it should look within the scope you provided.

```
e.search.in=range
e.search.from=[addr]
e.search.to=[addr]
```

if you want to search whole memory use
`e.search.in=dbg.maps`

Good luck!